# Android Poor Image Quality When Saving Image From takePicture callback

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have looked at a bunch of other stack answers regarding poor Android camera images but they all seem to be from people who were grabbing the thumbnail and then scaling that up.

My issue is that even the image being saved in the library is coming out very poor quality.Its coming out with dull colors and more pixelated.

Here is my callback where I save the image to the library. Can you see any reason why I am losing image quality when I save it?

Here is the callback

```
  @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getBaseContext(), new String[]{pictureFile.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/png"}, null);
```

Here is where I get the outputMediaFile

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "PumpUp");
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".png");
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".png");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

UPDATE:

The bitmap data is giving me a width and height of 320. Do you know why it got scaled down?

UPDATE 2:

This code will print out 320W 240H

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,imageBitmap.getWidth() + "  h " + imageBitmap.getHeight());
}
```

Why is my image getting scaled down before it even gets the callback?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are getting only a thumbnail representation of the image..

For getting the image in it's exact size you have to pass an `URI` as an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` parameter for camera intent

```
 //create file at path where you like
 File photo = new File();
 URI resultUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultUri);
 //this resultUri would be  your final image
```

Comment: Interesting, I read nothing of this in any documentation. Where did you find this?:)

Comment: @Aggressor we are doing like this

Comment: @Aggressor is it fixed your issue? if so can you accept and upvote the answer?

Comment: Yes just got into work and I am trying it shortly

Comment: Hmm this does not to seem to work, the image saved to the gallery is poor quality still

Comment: I found the answer and updated my question.